# Connection changes after waking from sleep

Tags: linux, tcp, netstat

On Debian, Linux, I am using netstat to monitor connections. After waking my system from sleep, I noticed a change in one of the connections, using port 6667 for irssi (identified by PID).

I like to suspend my computer and wake from sleep, with my irssi open in a terminal emulator.

After performing `/reconnect` on irssi, everything returned to the oftc.net domain.

Below is the output of `netstat` at the point of performing `/reconnect`

[image: terminal output at the point of reconnecting]

Why did the connection change from `oftc.net` to `getic.rdsnet.ro`? Is my system security compromised? What can I do to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid, this is simply one of the several servers that host OFTC service.

Here is an explanation:

```
~$ dig +short irc.oftc.net
91.217.189.50
109.74.200.93
130.239.18.116
81.18.73.124
~$ for ip in $(dig +short irc.oftc.net|grep -E '^[0-9]') ; do dig +short -x ${ip} ; done
farad.oftc.net.
solenoid.acc.umu.se.
getic.rdsnet.ro.
plasma.oftc.net.
```

When querying DNS for ip for irc.oftc.net, DNS returns 4 records: this is round robin DNS, a kind of "poor people load balancing" ;-)

The server you reconnected to is legitimate as you can see...

**EDIT**
If you're un-familiar with Linux and dig command, then:

- `dig` is to request DNS server.
- `dig +short` only output usefull information (pretty cool for scripting).
- `dig -x` will do reverse DNS request (getting the name from the IP).